# Fetch list of values for auto_complete

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have the following working bash_completion code

```
 _supdeploy()
{
    local cur prev opts cword
    _init_completion || return

    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    first="${COMP_WORDS[1]}"
    opts="option1 option2 --help"

    case "${first}" in
        option1)
            if [[ "$cur" == * ]]; then
               COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '--arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --help' -- "$cur" ) )
            fi
            return 0
            ;;
        option2)
            if [[ "$cur" == * ]]; then
               COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '--arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --help' -- "$cur" ) )
            fi
            return 0
            ;;

        *)
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
            return 0
            ;;
    esac
} &&
complete -F _supdeploy supdeploy
```

When I tab, I first get the list of `opts`, and if I use one of the opts, press tab again, I get the arg list for these option.

What I'm trying to do is to pre-fill some of these arguments which have a value assigned to them with a list to choose from.
The examples I looked at where all using these from the top level, like the opts in my case, but I want to use it on the 2nd level.
I already tried to implement a 2nd `if` inside the case loop, and check for example if `$cur` is one of the arg.
But it never worked, was still just printing the full list on tab.

Comment: What is the purpose of `[[ "$cur" == * ]]`? "`*` matches any string, including the null string." therefore this test will always succeed.

Comment: `"${first}"` could/should be "$first", there is no difference but the later is canon.

Comment: `[[ "$cur" == * ]]` will make a tab show all available args for a given command.

Comment: No, `[[ "$cur" == * ]]` is an expression that will always return success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the possible options to `--arg1` in the `option1` case, you can check if the previous word (`prev="{COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"`) equals `--arg1`:

```
    case "$first" in
        option1)
            case "$prev" in
              --arg1)
               COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W 'A Ba Bb C' -- "$cur" ) )
               return 0
               ;;

              --arg2)
               COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '11 12 2 3' -- "$cur" ) )
               return 0
               ;;

              *)
                COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '--arg1 --arg2 --arg3 --help' -- "$cur" ) )
                return 0
                ;;
            esac
            ;;

        option2)
```

If checking the previous word is not flexible enough, you could implement more complex logic. From the man page:

> ```
> COMP_WORDS
>        An array variable (see Arrays below) consisting of the  individ-
>        ual  words  in the current command line.  The line is split into
>        words as readline  would  split  it,  using  COMP_WORDBREAKS  as
>        described above.  This variable is available only in shell func-
>        tions invoked by the  programmable  completion  facilities  (see
>        Programmable Completion below).
> ```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. I can use that as a framework to progress further now.